# "Should 'creature' be pluralized to 'creatures' in the sentence 'In the fish village, the small fish weren’t the only glowy creature'?"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

The sentence is "In the fish village, the small fish weren’t the only glowy creature" . Should the word "creature" be pluralized to "creatures" to match the plural form of "fish"?

BTW, the "fish" here stands for a group of fish. Which one is the correct form?

> In the fish village, the small fish weren’t the only glowy creature

OR

> In the fish village, the small fish weren’t the only glowy creatures

Comment: You forced the plural 'creatures' when you chose the plural 'weren't'.

Comment: "The sentence"? You need to say where you found this sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be "creatures". It is possible for a plural subject to have a singular predicate nominative. (For example: "Alice and Bob are a nice couple.") However, singular "creature" would not make much sense here, because a reader would not normally expect multiple "fish" to be one "creature".